# Weird things around the anchor link tag in bootstrap 4.2.1

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, anchor

I have a strange thing near anchor tags when added, I don't know how to delete them. These are some kind of wavy lines near the card in bootstrap 4.2.1.

[image: The final project]
[image: The test index.html file, the code of it is below]

The code is exactly like that:

```
            <!doctype html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Masny start!</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
                <link rel="icon" href="zdjecia/logodark.png">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
                <meta name="description" content="Wynalazki są naszą pasją, a ich rozprzestrzenianie naszym celem.">
                <meta name="keywords" content="wynalazki, inventions, wynalazek, invention">
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light" rel="stylesheet">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

            </head>

            <body>

                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <!-- first row -->
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <a href="kat/muzyka.html" class="reset-links">
                                <div class="card mt-5 ml-5" style="width: 23rem; height: 23rem;">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <p class="card-text text-dark">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi saepe iste accusamus suscipit quibusdam dolore doloribus esse minus reiciendis libero? Consequuntur voluptatibus corrupti quas excepturi ad possimus blanditiis, voluptas ratione.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="js/dropdown_hover.js"></script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

CSS:

```
            body {
                background-color: dimgray;
                color: white;
                font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
            }
            .reset-links, .reset-links:hover, .reset-links:active, .reset-links:focus {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: black;
            }
```

It makes those lines only when going onto a different page and going back. I've tried to delete this effect but I don't know what causes it...

I'd really appreciate if someone told me which value should I change in css to get rid of it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it from what you shared but I suspect that you may need: `outline: none`

Comment: Thanks it's working!